# Firebase database cant retrieve data into class (returns null)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getvalue

been watching tutorials and forums, tried everything, still cant find the solution. When i retrieve data with getValue() and put it in object, it sees the values, but when i try to a the to a class with getValue(Kontaktas.class) the values are null. What am i doing wrong?

**MAIN**

```
    package com.juliusj.gym.easy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference mRef, mIn;
    List<Kontaktas> mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://easy-683ba.firebaseio.com/users");
        mIn = mRef.child("users");
        mIn.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //shake hands
                for (DataSnapshot unit : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Kontaktas value = unit.getValue(Kontaktas.class);
                    mList.add(value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Kontaktas.java**

```
    package com.juliusj.gym.easy;

public class Kontaktas {
    private String vardas;
    private String telefonas;

    public Kontaktas()
    {}

    public Kontaktas(String vardas, String telefonas){
        this.vardas = vardas;
        this.telefonas = telefonas;
    }

    public String getVardas() { return vardas; }

    public void setVardas(String vardas) {
        this.vardas = vardas;
    }

    public String getTelefonas() {
        return telefonas;
    }

    public void setTelefonas(String telefonas) {
        this.telefonas = telefonas;
    }
}
```

[image: databasePIC]

[image: debugerLOG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that I first see, is that your fields from your database and those from your model class are different! In your database your `Telefonas` field is capital `T` and in your model class you have `telefonas` with lower case `t`. Both fileds must be the same. You either change your the keys in your database, either change your model class. But i recommend you delete the actual data and add new data using your models class which is correct.

Also, if you are trying to print the values of your `mList` ArrayList outside the `onDataChange()` method, you'll get an empty list. This is because `onDataChange()` method has an asynchronous behaviour. To solve this, use the following code:

```
mIn.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Kontaktas> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot unit : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Kontaktas value = unit.getValue(Kontaktas.class);
            mList.add(value);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", mList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

If you want to use the `mList` outside `onDataChange()` method, you need to create your own callback and for that I recommend see the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**.

Comment: Thank you! The capital and lowercase letters changed it all. Can't believe i had spent 3 days trying to find the solution -_-